# Is Jicama root safe to eat every day?

Tags: nutrition, diet, food-safety, toxicity, toxins

Is 4-6oz of Jicama root safe to eat every day?

According to the following website, Jicama root contains a fat-soluble organic toxin that is linked to the development of Parkinson's disease.  It then seems to contradict itself a little by saying peeled roots are safe for human consumption.

I think their point is that peeled roots contain much less of the toxin, but given that the toxin is **fat-soluble**, it seems that build-up could occur if a person eats enough of it regularly.  The question is: *How much is too much?*

> **Safety profile**
>
> Jicama plant contains significant levels of fat-soluble organic toxin, rotenone. This toxin is concentrated especially in the leaf tops, stems and seed pods but at much lower concentrations in the roots. Several studies found that it linked to the development of Parkinson's disease. However, peeled roots are safe for human consumption, including in children. Rotenone works at cellular level inhibiting several metabolic enzymes like NADH dehydrogenase in the mitochondria. Outside, it used as environmentally safe broad-spectrum insecticide, piscicide (to poison fish), and pesticide.

Source: https://www.nutrition-and-you.com/jicama.html

Comment: Could you clarify why your quote says "peeled roots *are safe* for human consumption, including in children"? Have you a source that says otherwise or that somehow quantifies the trace amounts of rotenone in roots? (Potatoes contain solanine and chaconine and are safe to eat everyday, if you stick to tubers and abstain from the peels and greens…)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no study that would mention an association between **peeled jicama root** consumption and Parkinson's disease or any intoxication in humans.

**Rotenone** can be found in **[jicama seeds, stems and leaves](https://www.britannica.com/plant/jicama)** and, according to some [random](https://naturallysavvy.com/eat/jicama-a-veggie-you-should-know-better-recipes/) [sources](https://www.emetabolic.com/locations/centers/Mandarin/blog/eat-well/never_thought_youd_be_eating_jicama_root/) in jicama **root skin.** Severe intoxication can occur after eating jicama seeds ([PubMed, 2005](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16241030)).

I haven't found any source that would claim there is any meaningful amount of rotenone in the **peeled jicama root.**

**Rotenone as a pesticide** (but not as part of any food) ingestion has been linked to Parkinson's disease in humans, though ([Environmental Health Perspective](https://ehp.niehs.nih.gov/doi/full/10.1289/ehp.1002839)).

**In conclusion,** there seems to be no evidence to recommend against daily consumption of peeled jicama roots in aim to avoid any disease.